# EF Code First Migrations Enabled For Existing Database After EF Upgrade

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I recently upgraded an `MVC3` web application using `Entity Framework 4.3` Code First with an existing database to `MVC5` and `Entity Framework 6`.  We don't use code first migrations and all DB changes are performed manually.  This worked perfectly before the upgrade, and I didn't have any special code in my app that explicitly instructed Entity Framework to disable migrations.

After upgrade, I started getting SQL Exceptions, and upon inspection realized that EF was sending CREATE statements to the database for some of the Views mapped in the model.

I've researched this, and it appears that this is supposed to be an explicit setting using the "`Enable-Migrations`" command in Package Manager Console (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398#step2).

Further research led me to the `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null)` command to turn off migrations, and that appears to have worked.

While I have resolved the problem, I'd like to know what's going on here.  Is this now a setting that is enabled by default and always requires manually disabling, or is something else going on.  I'm concerned that there may be other hidden implications and I'd like to better understand what's happening.